# preg_replace to replace all matches

Tags: php, regex, forms, preg-replace

Hi I am creating a generator form to replace
some CSS code I have ... it will find all the 
class and id as well as dots, and place .class 
in front of them ...

now it's only replacing the first match 
I have set the limit to -1 ... why it's ignoring it??

html:

```
<form action="get_html.php" method="post" id="form">
    html:<textarea rows="50" cols="80" id="html_box" name="html" type="text" align="texttop"></textarea>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

get_html.php

```
<?php 
    $html= $_POST["html"]; 
    $string = (string)$html;
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/^[.]/';
    $patterns[1] = '/^[#]/';
    $patterns[2] = '/,/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = '.class .\1';
    $replacements[1] = '.class #\1';
    $replacements[2] = ', .class \1';
    $str= preg_replace($patterns,$replacements, $string, -1);
?>
<textarea rows="50" cols="80"><?php echo $str; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: typically wrong approach

Comment: some pointers please really no ideas how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two regexes can only match at the start of the string (`^` only matches at the start of each line if you use the `/m` modifier).

But those regexes probably wouldn't do what you want them to do. Right now you're looking for a dot or a hash, but only if they are the first character of the string/line (or any comma) and replace them with `.class` and themselves. The `\1` is useless because you don't have a capturing group in your regex.